# Remote PXE server files

Tags: linux, windows, pxe-boot, tftp, winscp

Is it possible to view the contents of a remote PXE/TFTP Server on a Windows PC?
I would like to get the pxelinux.0 file off of a remote server,
but when I connect using WinSCP or just Explorer I get prompted for credentials.
When an user PXE boots they don't get prompted for credentials... How does this work?

Answer (score 3):

It's a tftp server, so you'll need to use a tftp client.

Comment: I tried several TFTP clients... Each time I set the remote file to "pxelinux.0" but that just results in a timeout error..

Answer (score 1):

PXE uses DHCP and TFTP.  BIOSes that have PXE enabled ask the DHCP server whether there are PXE services available when they request an IP address.  If PXE is available, the DHCP server includes that information along with the IP address.  The PXE client then downloads the boot image via TFTP and boots off it.

Depending on whether or not the administrator has set restrictions on which clients it will serve, you may or may not be able to download the image file via TFTP.  It may or may not be in a format which you're able to view.

Is there a specific problem you're trying to solve by viewing the PXE boot image?

Comment: Thanks, this explained a lot.. Our old network administrator left a while ago, he used a remotely hosted PXE-Server (which I can't really get access to..) to install all computers on the network. Inside the PXE Boot Image are some IP-Adresses and usernames which I need to change to our new servers. I don't want to create a blank image because our installs are heavily modified. Creating an image from a PC which is already installed isn't an option either.. Im just out of ideas right now.. Thinking about using a network sniffer  to capture the image